# icCube connect to SQL Express file (.mdf)

Tags: connection, sql-server-express, iccube

I read in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724548/olap-on-sql-express/6401046#6401046) post that it is somehow possible to connect to SQL Express. This post is pretty old and I hope it is still possible somehow to make a connection to a .mdf file (SQL Express database).

How can you set-up a connection to this sort of file?

Comment: You'll have to install the mdf into an SQL Server and from there use it in icCube.

Comment: I hoped there was a direct way to do this so there is no (manual) step to upload it into SQL Server. Alas.

Comment: that's another question for so that I don't know how to answer

Comment: Will keep an eye open for a solution and post it here if I find one.